# How I can display a pic without change path in html file?

Tags: php, html

I have the link in index.html:

```
<a href="script.php?file.html">file</a>
```

In file.html there is relative link to pic:

```
<img src="pic.gif"/>
```

When user click the link then script shows to him the file.html (with some changes).
All works fine if I put script.php to the same folder where is file.html and pic.gif.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents($_GET['file']);
...something add...
echo $html;
?>
```

But if I put script in other folder i.e. 'scripts', then user cannot see images. 
I have a lot folders with htmls and I cannot put script to every folders. I prefer 'script' folder. 
Also I wouldn't want to make any changes in files.html (make absolute path).

Is there any simple decision for display pics when script.php are not near pics?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I could be wrong but it looks like English is not your first language. There are plenty of stack sites for different languages, perhaps you would be more comfortable on one of those where you can ask your question properly?

Comment: Your question is really unclear to me. Can you maybe include a layout of your site, and **what it is that you're trying to achieve**? Do you have several folders with pictures and want maybe to generate an introductory page for them? Or what else?

Comment: give the pic an absolute path rather than a relative one, at least that's how i'm interpreting the question

Comment: @smith: I see that problem in relative path. I wish I wouldn't change the file.html more.  I only ask if there is any simple decision (like chdir() but temporarily). Can I give absolute path to all pics in all files without change files? That is the question!

Comment: the script that runs `file_get_contents` could rewrite the paths  before echoing; but this whole thing seems a little odd.

Comment: yes script could change paths but if file contents a lot pics then it takes a lot time. The chdir() don't spent time, but unsafely.

Comment: What is odd thing if I add a little search capabilities to every docs files, especially if it need to customer? All works fine yet... except paths to pics.

Comment: yes script could change paths and I think I get such way, but if file contents a lot pics then it takes a lot time.